# Run a server side function in Google App Script using google.script.run

Tags: google-apps-script

Below is my HTML file in Google App Script.

It creates a dialogue box on a spreadsheet. When the ok button is pressed I want it to run a function that I have created in App script and also close the dialogue box.

When I am clicking OK the app script code is not running. What can I do better?

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<h3>Welcome</h3>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SEOMango</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Ok" class="create ok_button" 
onclick="close1();" id="ok_button"/>


<!--JQUERY-->
<script 
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
<script>
function close1()
{
google.script.host.close();

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler.doSomething();

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What success handler? Note that you should close the page in the success handler, otherwise the server call will never be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
function close1()
{
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(end).doSomething();
}
function end()
{
   google.script.host.close();
}
```

You first need to execute you function on google side `doSomething`then if it is successful call `end()` function with `google.script.host.close()` inside of it to close your sidebar/dialog box.

as @tehhowch mentionned it you are here closing your Html page before executing your function `doSomething()`.